# Can I iconify new windows by default in Lubuntu?

Tags: window, focus

I want to know if I can start up programs without their Windows opening before I select them, either with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> or from my task-bar.

Right now if I want to use terminal while I'm loading a web browser (which takes 5-10 secs on my PC), I might be typing something in terminal, and then get interrupted when the web browser opens.

I've tried editing `lubuntu-rc.xml` as suggested by [this post](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Configuration#Focus), which suggested changing the "yes" in `<focusNew>yes</focusNew>` to "no", then rebooting, but it didn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: your title and actual question is completely different!! why?

Comment: What do you mean? An iconified window is one that is minimized to the taskbar, I want windows to start out that way so they don't interfere with my current window.

Comment: Sorry, that term is new to me! You may also want to use minimized or unfocused.

Comment: @Nephenine There's no need to make unnecessary edits to the content of the question. If you *need* the question to be the revision you rolled back to, we can keep it there, but it doesn't improve readability of the post and is honestly unnecessary in my opinion.

Comment: @Nephenine I've given an answer. You can check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thanks to your researched question. It would take more time if you did not mention or link that configuration page.

**Why your settings didn't work?**

Actually, you're looking at wrong settings. What you were changing is mouse focus mode, whether it would follow current mouse or stay unfocused etc.

**Correct Settings:**

To correctly implement this, you need these changes in `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` file.

In the `<applications></applications>` tags, create a new `<application></application>` tab with these settings.

```xml
<applications>
  <application type="normal">
    <focus>no</focus>
    <iconic>yes</iconic>
    <layer>below</layer>
  </application>
</applications>
```

**Explanations:**

- `<application type="normal">` sets the rule for all normal windows. Other window types include `dialog`, `splash`, `menu` etc. Look at the `lubuntu-rc.xml` file for details
- `<focus>no</focus>` - is setting focus for new window. New window will be unfocused
- `<iconic>yes</iconic>` - is setting the windows to start at minimized.
- `<layer>below</layer>` - is setting the window below the current active window. Just to be extra safe.

**Suggestions:**

You can want to change the combination. For example, it seems, making the layer `below` and focus to `no` will achieve the job.

**Test Results:**

I tested this settings with `lxterminal`, `textadept`, `leafpad`, `firefox`, `gedit`. Most of them worked and opened in taskbar.

However, It seems if you start firefox by just typing `firefox` in terminal, it would raise for apparently no reason after 2-3 seconds. You need to use `firefox >/dev/null 2>&1` to prevent this. Also, Gedit seems to be not following these settings. But most of lxde-compatible application should work.

**Extra:**

I made a pastebin clip in case you need to look at the full file. Here it is http://pastebin.com/f76X8qNy